# Any suggestions on how to write factories for DTOs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, factory, fixtures, python-dataclasses

I use DTO to communicate data between different layers/classes in my application. So during the testing of these classes, I had to manually create objects of these data classes with some dummy data which is one serious pain point for me any suggestion on automating this stuff like factoryboy for Django models.

Comment: I have used FactoryBoy for this purpose.

Comment: factory boy was developed to ease the creation of test fixtures! if u want to build a test fixture, go on!
but if u are looking for building DTOs i would pick some other package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a user DTO like below.

```
import dataclasses
@dataclasses.dataclass
class UserDetailsDto:
    user_id: int
    user_name: str
    profile_pic: str
    is_admin: bool
```

for that DTO, I write a factory like this.

```
import factory
import factory.fuzzy
class UserDetailsDtoFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetailsDto

    user_id = factory.sequence(lambda n: n)
    user_name = factory.sequence(lambda n: 'Username-%s' % n)
    profile_pic = factory.sequence(lambda n: 'Dummy Profile Pic %s' % n)
    is_admin = factory.Iterator([True, False])
```

I'm using this approach successfully.
You can also try this.
Hope this helpful to you.

Comment: how about the DRF's serializers?I think they would do the same thing and provide validation methods as well.

Comment: u can use this package for DRF serializers: https://github.com/oxan/djangorestframework-dataclasses